# How to get the same level element value in JS?

Tags: javascript

I faced with the problem with DOM structure in JavaScript.

I have several div elements with class .item

```
<div class="item">
  <p class="title">Lorem ipfsum</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <a class="bttn">Button</a>
</div>
```

So, how can I get the text value of .title by clicking on the bttn on the same .item? In JQ it looks like this `$(this).parent('.title')` but how can I do it in Vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have several divs with class item and you need to translate in pure JS the click event handler for each button and the related logic I would suggest to use:

- [Document.querySelectorAll('.bttn')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)
- [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and its Polyfill in order to assure compatibility among browsers.

Another way is to use:

> [Node.previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling): The Node.previousSibling read-only property returns the node immediately preceding the specified one in its parent's childNodes list, or null if the specified node is the first in that list.

```js
//
// closest Polifyll: from MDN
//
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest = function (s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s), i, el = this;
        do {
            i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {
            };
        } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement));
        return el;
    };
}

function previousSiblingByClassName(ele, className) {
    var el = ele;
    while (el = el.previousSibling) {
        if (el.classList != undefined && el.classList.contains(className)) {
            return el;
        }
    };
    return el;
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bttn'), function (ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        console.log('Using closest: ' + this.closest('.item').querySelector('.title').textContent);
        console.log('Using previousSibling: ' + previousSiblingByClassName(this, 'title').textContent);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <p class="title">Lorem ipfsum1</p>

    <p>...</p>
    <a class="bttn">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p class="title">Lorem ipfsum2</p>

    <p>...</p>
    <a class="bttn">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p class="title">Lorem ipfsum3</p>

    <p>...</p>
    <a class="bttn">Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember: jQuery is just JavaScript. It's a convenient layer over the top of some of the messy parts. You can access a nodes parent using [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode). Combine that with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and you've got a solution.

```js
document.querySelector('.bttn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.parentNode.querySelector('.title'));
});
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="title">Lorem ipfsum</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <a class="bttn">Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the clicked button parent, search for a `.title` element to retrieve its text as below:

```js
document.querySelector('.bttn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.parentNode.querySelector('.title').innerText);
});
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="title">Lorem ipfsum</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <a class="bttn">Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
this.parentNode.querySelector('.title');
```